# postgres - copy values from one column to another column (same table)

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I want to copy the entire content from one column to another (same datatype) and thought of a subselect to be part of the equasion.

```
UPDATE tab01 
  SET column2=(SELECT column1 FROM tab01);

ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

that error makes completely sense as the outpout of my subselect has many rows.

Is there a way to copy all values into the other coloumn, without creating any sort of loop around something like ...

```
UPDATE tab01 
  SET column2=(SELECT column1 FROM tab01 WHERE id=1)
  WHERE ID=1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
UPDATE tab01 
SET column2 = column1
```

I believe the above should work. No need for a subquery, the field should be available of the same row which is being updated.

(Per your comments, you did not want to filter which rows get updated, so I've removed the `WHERE` clause.)

Comment: `timestamp` in my example is the name of a column (which also has the datatype `timestamp`). That's pobably confusing, sorry. I have updated my question, to make this more clear.

Comment: @vrms Yes I understand that. You're allowed to reference other columns you want to use on the right hand side of the equals sign of an update statement.

Comment: almost! Leaving out the WHERE clause seems to touch all entries at once. thx

Comment: @vrms Gotcha, np. I was only matching your second example which also has a `WHERE` clause on which rows were being updated. But yes, either way, you can directly access other columns of the same row being updated.

Comment: yea. that (using a where clause) was what I was looking to avoid

Comment: I was losing my mind, thinking that this wasn't working, but really there was another script running _after_ my migration to seed the database, and it was changing the data in a way that I wasn't aware of and was confusing me. So I'll leave this hint here for others. Maybe your Postgres query _is_ working fine.